# How to handle 2 alert in Selenium WebDriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, alert

I have an automation scenario to perform a content searching. The problem happen in the search result screen where there are 2 Javascript alert popup appears at nearly the same time. I said nearly because the popup window appears one by one, not all of them at once. I managed to handle the first one, but not with the second one. NoAlertPresentException happened for the second alert handler code.

Here's where the alert happened:

```
    public WSSPage enterAndSearchContent(String title) {
        waitWSSPageLoaded();
        waitForElementTextWithEnter(searchTextField, title);
        waitWSSPageLoaded();
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent());
        Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
        alert.dismiss();
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent()); //NoAlertPresentException happened here
        Alert alert2 = driver.switchTo().alert();
        alert2.dismiss();
        return PageFactory.initElements(driver, WSSPage.class);
    }
```

I alse tried using `alert.dismiss();` twice but still it gives NoAlertPresentException at the second `alert.dismiss();` like the below code:

```
    public WSSPage enterAndSearchContent(String title) {
        waitWSSPageLoaded();
        waitForElementTextWithEnter(searchTextField, title);
        waitWSSPageLoaded();
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent());
        Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
        alert.dismiss();
        alert.dismiss(); //NoAlertPresentException happened here
        return PageFactory.initElements(driver, WSSPage.class);
    }
```

When I try manually dismissing the alert, the second alert appears almost instantly. I guess the problem is the code can't catch the second alert because it was too fast?
Is there any workaround for this problem? Thank you.

Note:
I'm using Firefox

Comment: Use windowHandle and get the id of the current window. now check for popup 1 and switch & dismiss. SwitchtoWindow with the window id marked down using windowHandle. now again check for popup 2 and switch and dismiss.

Comment: @santhoshkumar I tried as you said, but it can't switch to popup 2. From you suggestion it should be focus in main window, then switch focus to popup 1, dismiss. Then it should should back focus to main window, switch the to popup 2, dismiss. What happened to me was: after it focus back to main window, it stays. No switch to popup 2 i don't know why...

Comment: After focusing back to main window(popup 1 dismissed), is the popup2 visible and wait handled properly. Can i have your complete code to check from my local?

Comment: Yes, the popup2 is visible and the wait handled properly. I'm sorry I'm afraid I can't give you because it related to many source code, but I really appreciate your intention though. Thanks a lot.

Comment: After dismissing and switching back to main window. Can you do one refresh and try ?

Comment: you mean adding `driver.navigate().refresh();` before switch to popup2?

Comment: Yes..., Just give a try

Comment: still doesn't switch to popup2..

Comment: Sorry. I am not able to help you exactly without the application. Thanks.